# how can i stretch left "row"s to fill left side ? i use bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Left side -->
            <div class="col-xl-10 style">
                <div class="row" >
                    <div class="col-xl-12 style">Box1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" >
                    <div class="col-xl-6 style">Box3</div>
                    <div class="col-xl-4 style">Box2</div>
                    <div class="col-xl-2 style">Box7</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 style">Box4</div>
                    <div class="col-xl-9 style">Box5</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Right side -->
            <div class="col-xl-2 style">Box 2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Rem iure sed recusandae hic laborum, quae earum doloremque illo alias explicabo rerum sequi corrupti magnam, ipsam laudantium cupiditate! Necessitatibus, aliquam eaque?</div>
        </div>
    </div> 

.style{
    background-color: rgb(220, 222, 238);
    border: 1px solid black; 
}
```

i need to stretch boxes (1,2,3,4,5,7) so box1 should take a half of box6 height, and another 2 lines with box3, box2, box7 and box4, box5 take 25% for each

[image]

Comment: use flexbox maybe?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is set a few more classes on your elements to target them safely (`nth-child()` could work if your layout stays the same.).

So, I added `.left` and `.right` classes to your main elements.

Then, set the `left` class to be a `flex` parent with a flex direction of `column`.

Then we target all the `rows` with `flex: 0 0 25%` making them all 25% in height. I added a class to the first row called `.half`. We then set the `flex` properties to `flex: 0 0 50%` so it is half the height.

I created a small version (using `col-sm-x` classes) so you could see it when you run the snippet. Your code is in the second snippet.

```css
.style {
  background-color: rgb(220, 222, 238);
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}

.row.half {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Left side -->
    <div class="col-sm-10 style left">
      <div class="row half">
        <div class="col-sm-12 style">Box1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 style">Box3</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 style">Box2</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 style">Box7</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 style">Box4</div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 style">Box5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Right side -->
    <div class="col-sm-2 style right">Box 2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Rem iure sed recusandae hic laborum, quae earum doloremque illo alias explicabo rerum sequi corrupti magnam, ipsam laudantium cupiditate! Necessitatibus, aliquam eaque?</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.style {
  background-color: rgb(220, 222, 238);
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}

.row.half {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Left side -->
    <div class="col-xl-10 style left">
      <div class="row half">
        <div class="col-xl-12 style">Box1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-6 style">Box3</div>
        <div class="col-xl-4 style">Box2</div>
        <div class="col-xl-2 style">Box7</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-3 style">Box4</div>
        <div class="col-xl-9 style">Box5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Right side -->
    <div class="col-xl-2 style right">Box 2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Rem iure sed recusandae hic laborum, quae earum doloremque illo alias explicabo rerum sequi corrupti magnam, ipsam laudantium cupiditate! Necessitatibus, aliquam eaque?</div>
  </div>
</div>
```